# Detect Fullscreen key combination for various environment - JS

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, fullscreen, browser-detection

I need to show Fullscreen key combination for various environment in a message to User on my website.

That needs to be detected based on environment. For eg Safari+windows = "F11" and Safari+mac = "cmd+shift+F"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of showing the shortcut for various browser/OS combinations, why not use the [fullscreen api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode)? On MDN they give an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/fullscreen.html) that binds an event to the toggle-fullscreen:

```
  var videoElement = document.getElementById("myvideo");

  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
      if (videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        videoElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
    } else {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      toggleFullScreen();
    }
  }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good solution.
However, my RIA has a texbox for user entry on one page as well as it needs to go Fullscreen on launch.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that is a good solution.
However, my RIA has a texbox for user entry on one page as well as it needs to go Fullscreen on launch. The (Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT) works well for all the browser's except Safari. For safari we are moving exiting user from fullscreen and want a graceful message to show them how to go fullScreen back once they are done with entering text. For that I need to capture various environment key combinations.